# How to get the cpu usage per thread on Mac OSX

Tags: c++, api, macos, multithreading, cpu-usage

I am looking for an OS level API to account for cycles consumed by a specific thread in OSX.

This is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393006/how-to-get-the-cpu-usage-per-thread-on-windows-win32) question (and answer) but in OSX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to get this info from the [thread_basic_info](https://web.archive.org/web/20100116094127/http://www.fi.muni.cz/~xholer/macosx/xnu/thread_basic_info.html) structure, returned by a call to [thread_info](https://web.archive.org/web/20100116083924/https://www.fi.muni.cz/~xholer/macosx/xnu/thread_info.html).

Comment: links forbidden

Comment: Modified  links to point to archive.org .... but this answer is fairly old already, I expect many things happened in OSX in the meanwhile.