# c++ "GetThreadTimes" but with a better resolution

Tags: c++, windows, time

Is there a method with a better resolution than 100us that can get me the total time a thread was working (without the time it was sleeping or waiting).
thanks :)

Comment: Why?  As far as I know the kernel doesn't maintain any higher resolution (it is a FILETIME).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use QueryThreadCycleTime(), it counts cpu cycles.  You can't do better than that.  Available in Vista and up.  It doesn't count sleep nor wait time, I verified on Win7.

Comment: anything for windows XP and down? :)

Comment: Of course I knew you were going to say that.  Stop using a ten year old operating system.

Comment: @Hans tell this to my customers and they will laugh at you.