# Measuring cpu cycles or another unit that doesn't depends on cpu frequency and doesn't count time/cycles in Sleep? WinAPI C++

Tags: c++, debugging, winapi, profiling

I need a profiling feature in two ways. The first one is total time that the code spends and the second one is an unit that doesn't depends on cpu-freq and sleeps in the code. (The Profiling is needed for our software with own language/interpreter, it runs on Windows)

My problem is by the second one.

- Results with `GetThreadTimes` depends on cpu-freq and not accurate (10 - 15ms) see for more: [Why GetThreadTimes is wrong? Kalmbachnet](http://blog.kalmbachnet.de/?postid=28)
- `QueryThreadCycleTime` also depends on implementation. (and also counts in sleep, as i tested) see for more: [What
  does QueryThreadCycleTime actually count? OldNewThing](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160429-00/?p=93385)
- `QueryPerformanceCounter` is a accurate counter, but cpu-freq-change changes the result and sleeps are also included.

Is it possible what i want to do? or is there any other way? How/What does visual studio profiling do?

Note: I know that my question seems like a duplicate. I tried to comment some old answers to same questions (like: [Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532046/c-getthreadtimes-but-with-a-better-resolution)) to get better answers, but my comments are deleted after 1-2 days. (see: [meta for comments deleted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390465/put-a-self-delete-timer-on-some-comments))

**EDIT**: (My test code for `QueryThreadCycleTime`)

```
static void foo()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
    Sleep(20);

    for (int x = 0; x < 1000; x++)
      x = x + 1 - 1;
  }
}

static void testCycles()
{
  HANDLE hThread = nullptr;
  ::DuplicateHandle(::GetCurrentProcess(), ::GetCurrentThread(), ::GetCurrentProcess(), &hThread, 0, false, DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS);

  std::vector<ULONG64> results;
  results.resize(7);

  for (auto &tElapsed : results)
  {
    ULONG64 tStart = 0;
    ::QueryThreadCycleTime(hThread, &tStart);

    foo();

    ULONG64 tEnd = 0;
    ::QueryThreadCycleTime(hThread, &tEnd);

    tElapsed = tEnd - tStart;
  }

  ::CloseHandle(hThread);
}
```

And there is results;

with Sleep(20)

in Thread
123383
192271
128028
208208
277983
223377
155222

in Main-Thread
191616
120002
126258
125267
141934
204753
125243

with Sleep(1000)

in Thread
121595
143863
182068
307464
388448
342315
468244

in Main-Thread
289568
256256
348599
359328
234065
167849
299888

Comment: It is not possible to eliminate the effects of CPU-freq scaling because the difference between CPU and memory speed affects IPC (instructions-per-cycle). CPU-freq scaling (and HT) should be disabled/locked when doing performance measurement.

Comment: @rustyx if this situation (IPC) is ignorable, than is it possible?

Comment: Can I assume your bigger goal is to find activities in the program that you could remove in order to save a good percentage of overall wall-clock time? That is most effectively done by hand-analyzing a relatively small number of random-time stack samples. For this purpose many people just use "pause" or "Ctrl-C" in a debugger. While you're hunting for tools, try this. Here's a [*short video*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xPg3sRpdW1U&t=1s).

Comment: @MikeDunlavey your assume is true, but not me, user should analyze. we have our programming language (a special scripting language for process visualization and automation). we want to let user to analyze user's procedures and code. i will implement a tool, that measures user procedure time and so on. not only time but also cpu load.

Comment: In my experience `QueryThreadCycleTime` doesn't count in sleep.

Comment: @ssbssa As i wrote it depends on cpu (vendor model vs.). I added my test code. i testet it on both main-thread and another thread. but only on x64 application. The results are all different, but sleep increases the results.

Comment: Are you sure the difference isn't just the overhead of the sleep call itself?

Comment: @ssbssa i added results off my tests in the question. maybe it doesn't depends on how long it sleeps directly, but maybe there will be APC and due to APC, the result differs?