# Get the Percentage of Total CPU Usage

Tags: delphi, cpu, delphi-xe, performancecounter

I am trying to get the % of total CPU usage to a `label1.Caption`

I've searched and found these:

- didn't work - http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?345723-DELPHI-Get-CPU-Usage
- not what I need - http://delphi.cjcsoft.net/viewthread.php?tid=42837

  - also found bunch of solutions regarding calculating the Usage per process but that is not what i am looking for , i just want the total CPU usage 
    like this  widget :[image: http://s18.postimg.org/p8kemg7jt/ty_000.jpg]

  this is what i am working on :

[image]

I believe there is a simple way like when we get RAM usage.

```
 GlobalMemoryStatus(RamStats);
 Label1.Caption := Format('RAM: %d %%', [RamStats.dwMemoryLoad]);
```

Comment: When you say "didn't work", you should explain what didn't work about it. Did you get an error? An unexpected result? No result? Considering the code I see in that first link, I'm willing to bet you didn't assign the event handlers to the timer and buttons.

Comment: See also : http://stackoverflow.com/q/1393006/327083

Comment: got 0% result and wasn't true ..

Comment: i think it didn't work due to system compatibility with win8.1 and yes i started  a blank project just to make sure  ...
and no i am not interested in Usage per process ,**i need the total  CPU usage ** like this widget does :  http://s18.postimg.org/p8kemg7jt/ty_000.jpg 
-thanks

Comment: Well, in order to know the total usage, one would have to know the per-process usage.

Comment: You probably need to use AdjustTokenPrivileges so that your process can read the other process information.

Comment: I have taken a chance by posting this question again, as I believe some news has come up, [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33575514/get-the-percentage-of-total-cpu-usage-as-shown-in-windows-taskmanager/33575515#33575515)

Comment: I disagree that this is a duplicate, @Jerry. The other question asks how to get the CPU usage of a single process. This question asks how to get the CPU usage of the entire system. Although one possible answer to this question is to enumerate all the system's processes, get all their CPU usages, and add them together, it's not obvious to me that that's the *only* possible answer. Perhaps the OS provides a more direct way for that — maybe one that doesn't require the caller to have read privileges on all the other processes.

Comment: @RobKennedy I never said that was the only possible answer. And by "one would..." I meant that information is used for the total anyway, even if Windows is the "one" which does that calculation. That's also why it was a comment and not an answer - it's just an option.

Comment: @RobKennedy Agreed, the question as rephrased in the most recent edit seems not a duplicate.  Suggest you vote to re-open if you feel it suitable.

Comment: @RobKennedy It was a duplicate but the edits changed the question.

Comment: @RobKennedy I have added more to the answer, so now it adds up all cpu percentages for each process. Now im a bit in doubt how to proceed, because I see that in the mean-time, the other question got re-opended. Is there a way to move the answer including the 3 points to the original question?

Comment: Questions can have their answers merged. Flag your answer and request administrative assistance. Otherwise, no, there's no way keep the points with your answer. That's the risk you take when you post a question on behalf of someone else, especially when you're not really sure what the other person really meant to ask.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I found [t h i s](http://www.torry.net/samples/samples/hard/adcpuusage.zip)

does the job

```
uses adCpuUsage;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
i:integer;
u:string;
begin
  collectcpudata;
   for i:=0 to GetCPUCount-1 do

 u:=FloatToStr(Round(getcpuusage(i)*100));   //Round to approximate 1.0003 to 1

label1.Caption:=u
end;

end.
```

worked for me
[image]

Comment: its a component  very long to post  here

Comment: My comment stands. Post just that code that relates to the question that was asked.

Comment: Just some comments: it looks like you'll only get the cpu usage of the last CPU like this. And IntToStr() makes more sense than FloatToStr if you round first.

Comment: Just because it's your own answer to your own question, doesn't mean you get to defy the rules :-/

Answer (score 11):

I have found an article, [determine-cpu-usage-of-current-process-c-and-c](http://www.philosophicalgeek.com/2009/01/03/determine-cpu-usage-of-current-process-c-and-c/), about how to get the CPU usage of the current process.

Now we need to do a bit more to compute the Total CPU usage percentage by adding up CPU usage percentage for each running processes:

```
function GetTotalCpuUsagePct(): Double;
var
  ProcessID: TProcessID;
  RunningProcessIDs : TArray<TProcessID>;
begin
  Result := 0.0;
  RunningProcessIDs := GetRunningProcessIDs;

  DeleteNonExistingProcessIDsFromCache(RunningProcessIDs);

  for ProcessID in RunningProcessIDs do
    Result := Result + GetProcessCpuUsagePct( ProcessID );

end;
```

After getting running process id's, we start out calling 
`DeleteNonExistingProcessIDsFromCache` to clean up the cache, that holds previous Cpu usage times needed in `GetProcessCpuUsagePct`: Every process that has been stopped since last query is removed from this cache.

The `GetProcessCpuUsagePct` is the core, which is a translation of [determine-cpu-usage-of-current-process-c-and-c](http://www.philosophicalgeek.com/2009/01/03/determine-cpu-usage-of-current-process-c-and-c/). This function needs to retrieve the previous reading from the Cpu Usage Cache `LatestProcessCpuUsageCache` (global in the unit) using the ProcessID.
Note, it is not recommended to call `GetToalCpuUsageCpu` less than every 200 ms, as it may give wrong results.

```
function GetProcessCpuUsagePct(ProcessID: TProcessID): Double;
  function SubtractFileTime(FileTime1: TFileTIme; FileTime2: TFileTIme): TFileTIme;
  begin
    Result := TFileTIme(Int64(FileTime1) - Int64(FileTime2));
  end;

var
  ProcessCpuUsage: TProcessCpuUsage;
  ProcessHandle: THandle;
  SystemTimes: TSystemTimesRec;
  SystemDiffTimes: TSystemTimesRec;
  ProcessDiffTimes: TProcessTimesRec;
  ProcessTimes: TProcessTimesRec;

  SystemTimesIdleTime: TFileTime;
  ProcessTimesCreationTime: TFileTime;
  ProcessTimesExitTime: TFileTime;
begin
  Result := 0.0;

  LatestProcessCpuUsageCache.TryGetValue(ProcessID, ProcessCpuUsage);
  if ProcessCpuUsage = nil then
  begin
    ProcessCpuUsage := TProcessCpuUsage.Create;
    LatestProcessCpuUsageCache.Add(ProcessID, ProcessCpuUsage);
  end;
  // method from:
  // http://www.philosophicalgeek.com/2009/01/03/determine-cpu-usage-of-current-process-c-and-c/
  ProcessHandle := OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION or PROCESS_VM_READ, False, ProcessID);
  if ProcessHandle <> 0 then
  begin
    try
      if GetSystemTimes(SystemTimesIdleTime, SystemTimes.KernelTime, SystemTimes.UserTime) then
      begin
        SystemDiffTimes.KernelTime := SubtractFileTime(SystemTimes.KernelTime, ProcessCpuUsage.LastSystemTimes.KernelTime);
        SystemDiffTimes.UserTime := SubtractFileTime(SystemTimes.UserTime, ProcessCpuUsage.LastSystemTimes.UserTime);
        ProcessCpuUsage.LastSystemTimes := SystemTimes;
        if GetProcessTimes(ProcessHandle, ProcessTimesCreationTime, ProcessTimesExitTime, ProcessTimes.KernelTime, ProcessTimes.UserTime) then
        begin
          ProcessDiffTimes.KernelTime := SubtractFileTime(ProcessTimes.KernelTime, ProcessCpuUsage.LastProcessTimes.KernelTime);
          ProcessDiffTimes.UserTime := SubtractFileTime(ProcessTimes.UserTime, ProcessCpuUsage.LastProcessTimes.UserTime);
          ProcessCpuUsage.LastProcessTimes := ProcessTimes;
          if (Int64(SystemDiffTimes.KernelTime) + Int64(SystemDiffTimes.UserTime)) > 0 then
            Result := (Int64(ProcessDiffTimes.KernelTime) + Int64(ProcessDiffTimes.UserTime)) / (Int64(SystemDiffTimes.KernelTime) + Int64(SystemDiffTimes.UserTime)) * 100;
        end;
      end;
    finally
      CloseHandle(ProcessHandle);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Here is a screen shot of the result on a Windows 7.

[image: TotalCpuUsageWin7.png]

Full Listing of unit:

```
unit uTotalCpuUsagePct;

interface

  function GetTotalCpuUsagePct : Double;

implementation

uses
  SysUtils, DateUtils, Windows, PsAPI, TlHelp32, ShellAPI, Generics.Collections;

type
  TProcessID = DWORD;

  TSystemTimesRec = record
    KernelTime: TFileTIme;
    UserTime: TFileTIme;
  end;

  TProcessTimesRec = record
    KernelTime: TFileTIme;
    UserTime: TFileTIme;
  end;

  TProcessCpuUsage = class
    LastSystemTimes: TSystemTimesRec;
    LastProcessTimes: TProcessTimesRec;
    ProcessCPUusagePercentage: Double;
  end;

  TProcessCpuUsageList = TObjectDictionary<TProcessID, TProcessCpuUsage>;

var
  LatestProcessCpuUsageCache : TProcessCpuUsageList;
  LastQueryTime : TDateTime;

(* -------------------------------------------------------------------------- *)

function GetRunningProcessIDs: TArray<TProcessID>;
var
  SnapProcHandle: THandle;
  ProcEntry: TProcessEntry32;
  NextProc: Boolean;
begin
  SnapProcHandle := CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
  if SnapProcHandle <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
  begin
    try
      ProcEntry.dwSize := SizeOf(ProcEntry);
      NextProc := Process32First(SnapProcHandle, ProcEntry);
      while NextProc do
      begin
        SetLength(Result, Length(Result) + 1);
        Result[Length(Result) - 1] := ProcEntry.th32ProcessID;
        NextProc := Process32Next(SnapProcHandle, ProcEntry);
      end;
    finally
      CloseHandle(SnapProcHandle);
    end;
    TArray.Sort<TProcessID>(Result);
  end;
end;

(* -------------------------------------------------------------------------- *)

function GetProcessCpuUsagePct(ProcessID: TProcessID): Double;
  function SubtractFileTime(FileTime1: TFileTIme; FileTime2: TFileTIme): TFileTIme;
  begin
    Result := TFileTIme(Int64(FileTime1) - Int64(FileTime2));
  end;

var
  ProcessCpuUsage: TProcessCpuUsage;
  ProcessHandle: THandle;
  SystemTimes: TSystemTimesRec;
  SystemDiffTimes: TSystemTimesRec;
  ProcessDiffTimes: TProcessTimesRec;
  ProcessTimes: TProcessTimesRec;

  SystemTimesIdleTime: TFileTime;
  ProcessTimesCreationTime: TFileTime;
  ProcessTimesExitTime: TFileTime;
begin
  Result := 0.0;

  LatestProcessCpuUsageCache.TryGetValue(ProcessID, ProcessCpuUsage);
  if ProcessCpuUsage = nil then
  begin
    ProcessCpuUsage := TProcessCpuUsage.Create;
    LatestProcessCpuUsageCache.Add(ProcessID, ProcessCpuUsage);
  end;
  // method from:
  // http://www.philosophicalgeek.com/2009/01/03/determine-cpu-usage-of-current-process-c-and-c/
  ProcessHandle := OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION or PROCESS_VM_READ, False, ProcessID);
  if ProcessHandle <> 0 then
  begin
    try
      if GetSystemTimes(SystemTimesIdleTime, SystemTimes.KernelTime, SystemTimes.UserTime) then
      begin
        SystemDiffTimes.KernelTime := SubtractFileTime(SystemTimes.KernelTime, ProcessCpuUsage.LastSystemTimes.KernelTime);
        SystemDiffTimes.UserTime := SubtractFileTime(SystemTimes.UserTime, ProcessCpuUsage.LastSystemTimes.UserTime);
        ProcessCpuUsage.LastSystemTimes := SystemTimes;
        if GetProcessTimes(ProcessHandle, ProcessTimesCreationTime, ProcessTimesExitTime, ProcessTimes.KernelTime, ProcessTimes.UserTime) then
        begin
          ProcessDiffTimes.KernelTime := SubtractFileTime(ProcessTimes.KernelTime, ProcessCpuUsage.LastProcessTimes.KernelTime);
          ProcessDiffTimes.UserTime := SubtractFileTime(ProcessTimes.UserTime, ProcessCpuUsage.LastProcessTimes.UserTime);
          ProcessCpuUsage.LastProcessTimes := ProcessTimes;
          if (Int64(SystemDiffTimes.KernelTime) + Int64(SystemDiffTimes.UserTime)) > 0 then
            Result := (Int64(ProcessDiffTimes.KernelTime) + Int64(ProcessDiffTimes.UserTime)) / (Int64(SystemDiffTimes.KernelTime) + Int64(SystemDiffTimes.UserTime)) * 100;
        end;
      end;
    finally
      CloseHandle(ProcessHandle);
    end;
  end;
end;

(* -------------------------------------------------------------------------- *)

procedure DeleteNonExistingProcessIDsFromCache(const RunningProcessIDs : TArray<TProcessID>);
var
  FoundKeyIdx: Integer;
  Keys: TArray<TProcessID>;
  n: Integer;
begin
  Keys := LatestProcessCpuUsageCache.Keys.ToArray;
  for n := Low(Keys) to High(Keys) do
  begin
    if not TArray.BinarySearch<TProcessID>(RunningProcessIDs, Keys[n], FoundKeyIdx) then
      LatestProcessCpuUsageCache.Remove(Keys[n]);
  end;
end;

(* -------------------------------------------------------------------------- *)

function GetTotalCpuUsagePct(): Double;
var
  ProcessID: TProcessID;
  RunningProcessIDs : TArray<TProcessID>;
begin
  Result := 0.0;
  RunningProcessIDs := GetRunningProcessIDs;

  DeleteNonExistingProcessIDsFromCache(RunningProcessIDs);

  for ProcessID in RunningProcessIDs do
    Result := Result + GetProcessCpuUsagePct( ProcessID );

end;

(* -------------------------------------------------------------------------- *)

initialization
  LatestProcessCpuUsageCache := TProcessCpuUsageList.Create( [ doOwnsValues ] );
  // init:
  GetTotalCpuUsagePct;
finalization
  LatestProcessCpuUsageCache.Free;
end.
```

Test Code:

unit Unit1;

```
interface

uses
  Vcl.Forms, System.SysUtils, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.StdCtrls, System.Classes,
  Vcl.ExtCtrls,

  uTotalCpuUsagePct;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Timer1: TTimer;
    Label1: TLabel;
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // start cpu load thread
  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    begin
      while True do
      begin
      end;
    end).Start;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
  TotalCPUusagePercentage: Double;
begin
  TotalCPUusagePercentage := GetTotalCpuUsagePct();
  Label1.Caption := 'Total cpu: ' + IntToStr(Round(TotalCPUusagePercentage)) + '%';
end;

end.
```

Comment: I'm seeing some big discrepancies here. As a test, I'm loading up Filmora (video editing software) and exporting a project, which typically eats most or all of the CPU, especially for 4K. While Task Manager shows my CPU usage over 90%, this (fetching every 300msec) is reporting more like 10-15%. Only when my CPU hits 100% does this also report 100%. But anywhere in-between, it doesn't seem accurate at all.

Comment: Also in your test code, you appear to have spawned an anonymous thread, but then it does nothing, while a timer does the work instead. Was this an unfinished idea, I presume?

Comment: Another round of testing, and I noticed that actually when Task Manager shows CPU is at a constant 100%, this code reports less than 100%. I can only conclude that it's not accounting for some processes, probably due to privileges, or the lack thereof? By the way I observe the same even when running my app as administrator.

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve your goal using the [Performance Counters Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373078%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from Microsoft.

> **[Limited User Access Support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372183%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**
>   Only the administrator of the computer or users in the Performance Logs User Group can log and view counter data. Users in the Administrator group can log and view counter data only if the tool they use to log and view counter data is started from a Command Prompt window that is opened with *Run as administrator....* Users in the Performance Monitoring Users group can view counter data.

---

I have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63166/how-to-determine-cpu-and-memory-consumption-from-inside-a-process/64166#64166) - see *CPU currently used* - from the [Lanzelot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7381/lanzelot) user here on SO and I have done some porting to Delphi.

**Raw porting**:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  pdh in 'pdh.pas';

var
  cpuQuery: HQUERY;
  cpuTotal: HCOUNTER;
  i: Integer;

procedure init;
begin
  PdhOpenQuery(nil, 0, cpuQuery);
  PdhAddCounter(cpuQuery, '\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time', 0, cpuTotal);
  PdhCollectQueryData(cpuQuery);
end;

function getCurrentValue: Double;
var
  counterVal: TPdhFmtCounterValue;
begin
  PdhCollectQueryData(cpuQuery);
  PdhGetFormattedCounterValue(cpuTotal, PDH_FMT_DOUBLE, nil, counterVal);
  Result := counterVal.doubleValue;
end;
```

The example requires the `pdh` unit which I have grabbed from [here](https://github.com/Steema/TeeChart-VCL-for-VCL-Delphi-CBuilder--applications-samples/blob/master/v131016/TeePerfMonitor/Pdh.pas).
The `WinPerf` unit is needed by the `pdh` and I have downloaded it from [here](https://github.com/Steema/TeeChart-VCL-for-VCL-Delphi-CBuilder--applications-samples/blob/master/v131016/TeePerfMonitor/WinPerf.pas).

**Basic test in a console application**:

```
begin
  init;
  for i := 1 to 60 do begin
    //let's monitor the CPU usage for one minute
    WriteLn(getCurrentValue);
    Sleep(1000);
  end;
  PdhCloseQuery(cpuQuery);
end.
```

---

**A more useful example based on the `TThread` class**.
This allows to obtain different counters based on the parameter passed to the `ACounterPath` argument in the constructor.

**counterThread.pas**

```
unit counterThread;

interface

uses
  Classes, Windows, SyncObjs, pdh;

type
  TCounterNotifyEvent = procedure(AValue: Double) of object;

  TCounterThread = class(TThread)
    private
      FInterval: Integer;
      FWaitEvent: TEvent;
      FHQuery: HQUERY;
      FHCounter: HCOUNTER;

      procedure checkSuccess(AResult: Integer);
    protected
      procedure Execute; override;
      procedure TerminatedSet; override;
    public
      OnCounter: TCounterNotifyEvent;
      constructor Create(const ACounterPath: PChar; AInterval: Cardinal; ACreateSuspended: Boolean);
      destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

implementation

uses
  SysUtils;

procedure TCounterThread.checkSuccess(AResult: Integer);
begin
  if ERROR_SUCCESS <> AResult then
    RaiseLastOSError;
end;

constructor TCounterThread.Create(const ACounterPath: PChar; AInterval: Cardinal; ACreateSuspended: Boolean);
begin
  inherited Create(ACreateSuspended);
  FInterval := AInterval;
  FWaitEvent := TEvent.Create(nil, False, False, '');

  FHQuery := INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
  checkSuccess(PdhOpenQuery(nil, 0, FHQuery));
  checkSuccess(PdhAddCounter(FHQuery, ACounterPath, 0, FHCounter));
  //checkSuccess(PdhAddEnglishCounter(FHQuery, ACounterPath, 0, FHCounter));
  checkSuccess(PdhCollectQueryData(FHQuery));
end;

destructor TCounterThread.Destroy;
begin
  FWaitEvent.Free;
  if (FHQuery <> 0) and (FHQuery <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) then
    PdhCloseQuery(FHQuery);
  inherited;
end;

procedure TCounterThread.TerminatedSet;
begin
  inherited;
  FWaitEvent.SetEvent;
end;

procedure TCounterThread.Execute;
var
  counterVal: TPdhFmtCounterValue;
begin
  inherited;
  while not Terminated do begin
    checkSuccess(PdhCollectQueryData(FHQuery));
    FillChar(counterVal, SizeOf(TPdhFmtCounterValue), 0);
    checkSuccess(PdhGetFormattedCounterValue(FHCounter, PDH_FMT_DOUBLE, nil, counterVal));
    if Assigned(OnCounter) then
      OnCounter(counterVal.doubleValue);
    FWaitEvent.WaitFor(FInterval);
  end;
end;

end.
```

**Unit1.pas**

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls,
  counterThread;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    Label1: TLabel;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FCpuCounter: TCounterThread;
    procedure CpuCounterCounter(AValue: Double);
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}


procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FCpuCounter := TCounterThread.Create('\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time', 1000, False);
  //'\Processore(_Total)\% Tempo Processore'
  with FCpuCounter do begin
    FreeOnTerminate := True;
    OnCounter := CpuCounterCounter;
  end;
  Button1.Enabled := False;
end;

procedure TForm1.CpuCounterCounter(AValue: Double);
begin
  Edit1.Text := FloatToStr(AValue);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Assigned(FCpuCounter) then
    FCpuCounter.Terminate;
end;

end.
```

**Unit1.dfm**

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 123
  ClientWidth = 239
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  OnDestroy = FormDestroy
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Label1: TLabel
    Left = 8
    Top = 24
    Width = 97
    Height = 13
    Caption = 'Total CPU usage %:'
  end
  object Edit1: TEdit
    Left = 111
    Top = 21
    Width = 99
    Height = 21
    TabOrder = 0
  end
  object Button1: TButton
    Left = 111
    Top = 80
    Width = 99
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Start monitoring'
    TabOrder = 1
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
end
```

---

**OFF TOPIC** 
I'm currently at home and I've not a Delphi XE here so I coded it with Turbo Delphi, I have no `pdh` unit installed on my machine and I can't know at the moment if Delphi XE has the units.

---

**NOTICE** 
I have used the [PdhAddCounter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372204%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function instead of the [PdhAddEnglishCounter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372536%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) because the function reference is missing in the unit. Unfortunately, after I added the reference, the function was still missing in the `Pdh.dll` on my old Windows XP.

The `szFullCounterPath` of the `PdhAddCounter` is localized so I have to use the italian localized path on my Windows `\Processore(_Total)\% Tempo Processore`.

If you use the `PdhAddEnglishCounter` function or your locale is english, you have to use the path `\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time`.

If your system locale is other than english or italian, you have to find the path by yourself using the [PdhBrowseCounters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372542%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.
The very basic function usage which follows needs the [`PdhMsg`](https://github.com/Steema/TeeChart-VCL-for-VCL-Delphi-CBuilder--applications-samples/blob/master/v131016/TeePerfMonitor/PdhMsg.pas) unit.
See also MSDN [Browsing Performance Counters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371886%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for further reference.

```
function CounterPathCallBack(dwArg: DWORD_PTR): Longint; stdcall;
begin
  Form1.Memo1.Lines.Add(PChar(dwArg));
  Result := ERROR_SUCCESS;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  PDH_MAX_COUNTER_PATH = 255;//maybe ?
  BROWSE_DIALOG_CAPTION: PChar = 'Select a counter to monitor.';
var
  browseDlgData: TPdhBrowseDlgConfig;
  counterPathBuffer: array [0..PDH_MAX_COUNTER_PATH-1] of Char;
  status: LongInt;
begin
  FillChar(browseDlgData, SizeOf(TPdhBrowseDlgConfig), 0);

  with browseDlgData do begin
    {bIncludeInstanceIndex = FALSE;
    bSingleCounterPerAdd = TRUE;
    bSingleCounterPerDialog = TRUE;
    bLocalCountersOnly = FALSE;
    bWildCardInstances = TRUE;
    bHideDetailBox = TRUE;
    bInitializePath = FALSE;
    bDisableMachineSelection = FALSE;
    bIncludeCostlyObjects = FALSE;
    bShowObjectBrowser = FALSE;}
    hWndOwner := Self.Handle;
    szReturnPathBuffer := @counterPathBuffer[0];
    cchReturnPathLength := PDH_MAX_COUNTER_PATH;
    pCallBack := CounterPathCallBack;
    dwCallBackArg := DWORD_PTR(@counterPathBuffer[0]);
    CallBackStatus := ERROR_SUCCESS;
    dwDefaultDetailLevel := PERF_DETAIL_WIZARD;
    szDialogBoxCaption := BROWSE_DIALOG_CAPTION;
  end;

  status := PdhBrowseCounters(browseDlgData);

  case status of
    PDH_DIALOG_CANCELLED, ERROR_SUCCESS:
      ;
    else
      RaiseLastOSError;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.magsys.co.uk/delphi/

Get the MagWMI component.  It's free.

This component will allow you to access the WMI pretty easily which already has the info you want. I just tested an old program I had using this on Win 10 and it correctly found all 8 of my cores and the processor usage.

And then do something like this:

```
 var
   compname:string;
   WmiResults: T2DimStrArray ;
   instances, i : Integer
 Begin
    compname:=getcompname;  // a function in the MagWMI to get the computer name.
    MagWmiGetInfoEx (compname, '', '',
                       '', 'SELECT percentidletime FROM Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Processor', WmiResults, instances, errstr) ;
    for i := 1 to instances do
    begin
         // wmiresults[i,2] will hold the percentage for each processor found.
    end;
```

Comment: Instead of using an external component, one also can directly use the Microsoft WMIScripting Library, as described here: https://theroadtodelphi.com/2010/12/01/accesing-the-wmi-from-pascal-code-delphi-oxygene-freepascal

Answer (score 0):

I solve this way:

```
function TCPU.get_param_value(param_name: String): String;
var
  command,
  file_out: String;
  data_file: TStringList;

begin
  data_file := TStringList.Create;
  try
    try
      file_out := TPath.GetTempPath + FormatDateTime('yyyymmddhhnnss', Now) + '_CPUInfo.txt';
      comando := '"wmic cpu get '+param_name+' /value | find "'+param_name+'" > ' +
                  file_out + '&&exit"';

      // "runas" for admin privileges, or "open" to any user
      ShellExecute(0, 'open', 'cmd.exe', PChar('/k ' + command), nil, SW_HIDE);

      // Wait 4 sec to cmd release the process...
      Sleep(4000);

      data_file.LoadFromFile(file_out);
      Result := data_file.Values[param_name];

    except
      Result := '';
    end;

  finally
    TFile.Delete(file_out);
    data_file.Free;
  end;
```

In this way, you can get any param values from **wmic**