# How do I get to know the actual time slice given to a thread?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, multithreading, operating-system

I understand the actual time slice is variable depending on several factors such as the OS and the processor.

But is there a way I can make a thread count the time slice allotted to it during the time it has the CPU to itself?

Comment: use tools in sysinternals to check?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393006/how-to-get-the-cpu-usage-per-thread-on-windows-win32 ?

Comment: And for the record: I like this question. It gives food for thought; and implementing something where a thread can measure its own utilization sounds like an interesting challenge!

Comment: @GhostCat: Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question; but I *think*: probably not.

In order to **measure** this from inside the thread, the thread needs to know about **two** events:

1. Thread is started/resumed; gets CPU time; and starts running
2. Thread is "suspended", and stops execution

From there: even if you find a mechanism to tell a thread "you have just been resumed" - how could you tell the thread when it was suspended? In other words: you would need two hooks, that somehow notify the thread not only about "you are resumed"; but also about "you will be suspended soon"; so that the thread itself can do its bookkeeping.

Given your comment: yes, *if* the underlying OS allows to determine the duration of a CPU slice **and** the duration time is **constant**; then the thread would not need to know about "event 2".

Comment: Thank you. I was doubtful too because of the reasons you mention. If that's not possible, would it be possible to just read a variable from an operating system structure that tells you how much a time-slice measures?

Comment: I updated my answer; but still on the meta-level; as I am missing the in-depth .Net and Windows OS knowledge to give a really technical answer.